# how to access stdclass object in php?

Tags: php

This is my object:

```
$reportdata = stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [reportname] => reportname1
            [reportviews] => 20
            [reportpath] => reports/reportname1
            [thumbnailurl] => reports/thumbnailurl/thumbnailurl1.jpg
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [reportname] => reportname2
            [reportviews] => 20
            [reportpath] => reports/reportname2
            [thumbnailurl] => reports/thumbnailurl/thumbnailurl2.jpg
            [description] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        )


)
```

I am trying to access the individual values using `$reportdata[1]['reportviews']` but I get an error

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

How can I access `reportname` and `reportviews`?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but that's usually the mess you get when you try to convert an array without contiguous index into JSON and then back. Make sure you clean up your array index with `array_values()` before converting it to JSON to make sure it will be unserialized as a proper array instead of an object.

Comment: You can also use `json_decode($json, true)` so it creates everything as associative arrays instead of objects.

Comment: @Francis Please accept any answer below by clicking a green check mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
 $reportdata=json_decode(json_encode($reportdata),true);
```

then use this

```
$reportdata[1]['reportviews']
```

You will not get any error.

Comment: `json_decode` expects a string and you're passing it an object. So... no.

Comment: Try it once again

Comment: `mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`. Setting `assoc` to true will only affect the returned result. Input is always expected to be a string.

Comment: If you didn't notice - there's `json_encode($reportdata)` which gives a string. So all is fine here.

Comment: i am just try to make the object to Array then whats wrong with that ?

Comment: @u_mulder The answer has been edited in the meantime.

Comment: @Bibhudatta Sahoo Even if the answer is technically correct after the edit you are performing two completely unnecessary conversions which can be very expensive, especially for large objects.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:
`$reportdata->{1}->reportviews`

Comment: The key thing here is that `{ }` allows you to specify an expression as a property name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reportdata->{'1'}->reportname;
$reportdata->{'1'}->reportviews;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of the object like others have mentioned but wanted to give an alternative option.

> get_object_vars — Gets the properties of the given object
>
> array get_object_vars ( object $object )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
$arrReportData = get_object_vars($reportdata);
echo $arrReportData[1]->reportviews;
```

Note that this is non-recursive, so in your case you'll get an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The way you trying to access an element:

```
$reportdata[1]['reportviews']
```

suggest that the main object is an associate array. This code would work if your object is declare like below:

```
$reportdata = array(
  '1' => array (
    'reportname' => 'reportname1',
    'reportviews' => '20',
    'reportpath' => 'reports/reportname1',
    'thumbnailurl' => 'reports/thumbnailurl/thumbnailurl1.jpg',
    'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor.'
  ),
  :
);
```

But when the `stdClass Object` is used,  you can access an object property named in a variable as below:

```
$atr1 = '1'; $atr2 = 'reportviews';
print $reportdata->$atr1->$atr2;
```

Or using an expression notation:

```
print $reportdata{'1'}{'reportviews'};
```